# How can i transform the values of a "variable" DataFrame into new ones

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Im working with pandas module in python. In my script im trying to get each value of the DataFrame and transforming them in another DataFrame that every value are replaced by the number 1 (n times as the range of the number), like:

```
             A           B    
a            1           2             
b            2           3
```

to:

```
             A           B           
a            1           1             
a                        1 
b            1           1
b            1           1
b                        1
```

The problem is: These aren't fixes values. I want the script get a "model" created by me and output something like the above results. Otherwise, the DataFrame can have 1,2,3...30 columns, same with rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on standard 2D lists. Adaptation to pandas' DataFrame is straightforward:

```
lst = [['a',1,2,2], ['b',2,3,2], ['c',4,0,2]]

table = []
for cols in lst:
    name, size = cols[0], max(cols[1:])
    row = [[1]*col + [0]*(size-col) for col in cols[1:]]
    table.extend(list(zip([name]*size, *row)))
```

Here is the final content of `table`

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(table)
[('a', 1, 1, 1),
 ('a', 0, 1, 1),
 ('b', 1, 1, 1),
 ('b', 1, 1, 1),
 ('b', 0, 1, 0),
 ('c', 1, 0, 1),
 ('c', 1, 0, 1),
 ('c', 1, 0, 0),
 ('c', 1, 0, 0)]
```